# Prove inequality of 2 functions for every $ x \gt 1 $

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Prove that for every  $ x \gt 1$ exists:

$$ 2x^3 + x^2-2x < x^4+5x^2-5 $$

I got this on my calculus course at college,

can I get some suggestions? I'm really breaking my head on this, 
and frankly, I don't know how to start proving this.

Any idea will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(x) = (x^4 + 5x^2 - 5) - (2x^3 + x^2 - 2x) = x^4 - 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 5$. Then if you have that $g(1) > 0$ and $g'(x) > 0$ when $x > 1$, you have shown the claim. Intuitively this is because you have shown that the difference of the functions is positive at 1 and that the difference only increases afterwards.

You can check yourself that $g(1) > 0$. So now we want to show that $g'(x) > 0$ when $x > 1$. To do this we can apply the same approach again. Show that $g'(1) > 0$ and then show that $g''(x) > 0$ when $x > 1$. This process can be repeated until you have differentiated the function enough that it becomes easy to show that it is positive. In particular $g^{(4)}(x)$ is a linear function so it should be easy to show it is positive when $x > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to $x^4 - 2x^3 +4x^2 +2x-5 > 0$ which you can prove using derivatives.

[EDIT]: Actually the derivatives aren't necessary: just observe that the LHS of the inequality is equal to $(1+x)(x-1)(x^2-2x+5)$.

Comment: What is the approach of solving this using derivatives?

Comment: If you are unable to factor the polynomial, you can try to use them. I've edited the answer and added the factorisation.

Comment: Serial downvoter again in action...

Answer (score 0):

Given $2x^3 + x^2-2x < x^4+5x^2-5$, subtract both sides by $x^2$ to get $$2x^3-2x<x^2+4x^2-5.$$ Factor out wherever possible to get $$2x(x^2-1)<(x^2+5)(x^2-1)$$ whence we can cancel both sides by $x^2-1$ to get $$2x<x^2+5.$$ We are left to show that $x^2-2x+5>0$, given $x > 1$. So...
\begin{align}
x^2-2x+5&=x(x-2)+5 \\
&>1(x-2)+5\\
&=x-2+5 \\
&=x+3 \\
&>1+3 \\
&=4 \\
&>0.
\end{align}
If you write a formal proof, you can proceed backwards of this answer.